# How can I remotely execute a program on multiple clients from a web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, client-server, distributed

So I have the following requirement for a project I'm working on, and I can't figure out the best (or any, for that matter) way to do this.

I have an asp.net web app sitting on IIS at HQ. When a particular event occurs, I need to then show a message on a dynamically selected subset of PC's throughout the company. The message must be shown due to the time restraints of this process (4 hours reaction time) and we legally can't afford to not show the message.

So I need to do the following:

- Show a message to the users. I have a winforms app that puts up a dialog that the only way to get rid of it is to click a big "Acknowledge" button.
- To ensure that the message was shown. Some kind of report back that yes, it was shown and subsequently acknowledged.
- A way to react if the form is not shown.

I've considered the following:

- **PsExec** - Iterating over every node asynchronously in my web app to fire off a remote 
  executable sitting on each PC.
- **.NET Remoting** - I'm not familiar with this at all, and it lead me to look at WCF instead. Would it work for what I'm trying to do?
- **WCF Callbacks** - These seem to require a constant connection and I'm not sure what that means for our infrastucture. I imagined a client service that would kick off an app or show the form somehow.
- **Our scheduling software (Tidal Enterprise Scheduler)** - remotely executing an executable. This would introduce more points of failure.

In SO's opinion, what would be the best way to attack this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You say 'when a particular event occurs' - is that a user initiated event or system/timer event? The latter will be very hard to do reliably using a web based system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is:

1. Have a client app that is installed on each of the desktops
2. Have that app either (on a timed event) call a web service to get any message it needs to display or contact the database server directly to get the message it needs to display.
3. Once the message has been displayed, have the app tell the web service or sql server that it has been seen.  Record the date time and logged in user.

Your web app should simply store the message in the database; and, if you want a bit of robustness expose a web service that the desktop app calls to retrieve messages and mark them as viewed.  This would prevent needing to have the desktop apps talk directly to sql server AND would mean that the desktop app could be installed anywhere in the world.

The desktop app should be installed in such a way that it cannot be disabled / turned off / uninstalled.  There are a myriad of ways to do this.

I wouldn't use any of the methods you defined as they are complicated and introduce way too much brittleness.

**UPDATE**
A few ways to lock the app just off of the top of my head:

1. Have a watchdog service that runs as administrator which monitors the desktop app.  If it's ever killed then force it to restart.  You can do the monitoring through WMI.  Some AV software does this.  Be sure to take the users rights away from stopping services.
2. Remove the users ability to use or access the task manager.  A lot of virus variants do this and it's easy to do from [group policy settings](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Disable-Task-Manager-1-Line-Code33vb6_t15257.html).
3. If they are on a domain, make sure that your group policy settings force installation of your desktop app AND force it to auto run on windows startup.

---

If you really want it to be effective do the following:
Make sure your app notifies the home server once an hour that it is running.  Have the CEO send out a message stating that if the app is ever turned off the employee in question will be fired.  They might phrase it a little nicer than that.  Run audit reports on a regular basis and fire a couple people to scare the hell out of everyone else.  I guarantee no one will screw with it after that.

Be sure that the audit reports are confirmed by managers...  After all an employee might not be in that day. ;)

Comment: A discussion with colleagues here went along these same lines. Could you elaborate on the myriad of ways to lockdown an app? I am thinking windows service, but your implication says to me that there are better ways..?

Comment: @IronicMuffin: See updates.  One company I worked with did the last option.  The first week saw several people figure out how to disable it and several people were publicly walked out.  No one jacked with it afterwards.  If it is as legally important as you suggest then you should be able to get exec level sign off on that option.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: BTW, I believe that Vista and above prevents services from having a UI component; hence the need for a regular desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the HQ application set some records in a table that knows which clients need to be shown the message

```
Message [ComputerName, IsAcknowledged]
```

Then each client will look at that table when necessary to see if their ComputerName exists and IsAcknowleded == false. If it does, show the prompt to Acknowledge, update their record

Comment: I believe this is the route I will be taking, but the answer by Chris above is more detailed and applicable to the whole system. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Explore Publish and Subscribe design patterns. That might be the right solution to you. Basically its starting a service to which all your windows apps will register a callback and from your webapp, you can raise an event in the service that will publish it all the registered applications. The Publisher will have the logic to identify the subset of your PC based on the event and the source.

Comment: I liked where this was going, but the disadvantages showed a lack of guaranteed delivery and difficulty assuming a subscriber is available. I don't think this will work with my current needs.

Comment: Design patterns are generic solutions, you can always overcome those disadvantages with lots of robust option in .NET. Windows service on your web server is a viable option to have a service up and running all the time as long as your web app that triggers the event is avaiable...